# Mathematica does not export Turkish characters in a Graphics expression

Tags: graphics, export

When I export the following `Graphics` expression as a *PDF* (or *EPS*) file, the *Turkish* characters *ü* and *ç* do not appear.

```
Graphics[Text[Style["Türkçe", 72, Background -> White], {0, 0}]]
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Here is how it looks in *PDF* file.
[image: 1]

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: and for me - *Mathematica* 9, Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Mathematica v9.0, windows 7 64bit english version - with tr config works too. Is your OS Turkish Windows? If so it may change the fonts... Some fonts does not support Turkish properly...

Comment: I am using *Windows XP Professional TR* version together with *Mathematica 8.0*.    
@kguler: I guess I couldn't make it work, because there is no expoerted file.

Comment: Did you try SystemOpen[DirectoryName[AbsoluteFileName["turkce2.pdf"]]] to locate file? Because, I can create this file in my system without a problem.

Comment: I have figured out that it works fine when I export the figure in an *English* operating system. Tried it with *Windows XP Eng* and returned a good output.  @s.s.o I will try it tomorrow at work, thank you very much.

Comment: Works for me in version 11.3 on Windows 10 32-bit, Russian (My machine is 64-bit.).